# Angular: Add Custom pipe to addControl() element

Tags: angular, pipe

So I Have created a custom pipe that will allow me to remove white spaces from a textfield. Like so:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'removeWhiteSpace' })
export class removeWhiteSpacePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any) {
        if (!value) {
            return '';
        }

        return value.replace(/\s*/g, "");
    }
}
```

In the html file, If I add this to the value its fine, like so:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ value | removeWhiteSpace }}" />
```

However, due to a development in the project, we now add the value of the field using the `.addControl()` in the .ts file like so:

```
this.phoneNumber.addControl('publicPhoneNumber', new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7), Validators.maxLength(11)]));
```

and now we do not have a `value=""` in the html.

How do I use a custom pipe with the way this is implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="publicPhoneNumber" [value]="phoneNumber.get('publicPhoneNumber').value | removeWhiteSpace "/>
```

I may not be understanding your complete requirement. But you don't want to use the `value` input property then at max you have a listener for the form control changes and use your pipe like a service, something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.phoneNumber = this._fb.group({
    publicPhoneNumber: []
  })

  this.phoneNumber.get('publicPhoneNumber').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      this.phoneNumber.get('publicPhoneNumber').setValue(this._remSpacePipe.transform(val), {emitEvent: false})
  })
}
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrsxou

Comment: Sorry, because we have components split across components I need to use the .addControl method.

Comment: @Mark That is fine, are you saying that you don't have form group instance where your input resides? How is addControl preventing you from using `[value]="phoneNumber.get('publicPhoneNumber').value | removeWhiteSpace "`?

Comment: So, forgive me as i'm a junior but the guy that started this project (the lead dev) told me not to add value to the input html tags because we have embedded components in components and various form groups. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Mark Check the update if it helps you, I don't really understand why won't `[value]` be used instead. As of my knowledge, I know just these two ways of applying a pipe.

Comment: wil do, just a little busy at the moment but will let you know when I try it :) Thanks.